# Не работает ввод данных в форму сайта в safari и ie?

Tags: safari

Есть страница авторизации в системе. 2 поля (Логин и пароль). Использую библиотеки jquery, bootstrap, [библиотека для анимации](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/).
Суть проблемы: Даёт вводить только первый символ логина. В чём может быть проблема?

Подключены плагины:

- **[Jquery](https://jquery.com/)**
- **[InpitMasK](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/tree/5.x)**
- **[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)**

```html
<form method="post">
   <div class="logo"></div>
   <input class="form-control cfepm" type="text" name="login" value="" required="" autofocus="" placeholder="Логин">
   <input class="form-control cfepm" type="password" name="password" value="" required="" placeholder="Пароль">
   <input id="submit-login" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" value="Войти" name="submit" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
    <p class="text-muted">© 2017-2018</p>
</form>
```

Comment: А без библиотеки анимации работает?

Comment: @Eleferen Да, но коряво(дёргается).

Comment: Наличие кода, возможно, упростило бы поиск решения ;-)

Comment: @Eleferen Добавил)